# Smooth manifold with non-trivial inertia group? (wrt homotopy spheres)

Tags: homotopy-theory, gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

Let $\Theta_n$ be the set of orientation-preserving diffeomorphism classes of homotopy spheres, with abelian group structure given by #.  Then for any smooth manifold $M^n$ one defines the "inertia subgroup" as

$I(M)=${$\Sigma\in\Theta_n$ | $M$#$\Sigma\cong M$}

In other words, the inertia group is the set of homotopy spheres which fix the smooth structure on $M$.

Does anyone know an example of a diffeomorphism (as explicit as possible) between an $M$ and $M$#$\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is as exotic sphere?  Moreover, if the dimension were sufficiently large can we always find a diffeomorphism which induces the identity on $\pi_1$?

(The big question I'm trying to think about is "If $\Sigma$ is in the inertia group of $M$, how does its smooth structure get 'unraveled' in $M$?")

Comment: May be I'm being dense but when you say "the identity on $\pi_1$" what exactly do you mean? Fundamental group is assigned to a pointed space. Abstractly, $\pi_1(M)$ and $\pi_1(M\# \Sigma)$ will be isomorphic but how does the identity map between these abstract groups make sense?

Comment: It seems we asked the same question.
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48693/smooth-structures-on-the-connected-sum-of-a-manifold-with-an-exotic-sphere


Comment: You get some non-trivial examples with things like $\mathbb RP^{18}$, and $\mathbb RP^{20}$.  This is because the group of exotic spheres has elements of even order larger than $2$, and these projective spaces aren't orientable.   So when you connect-sum with an exotic sphere, you can slide the summation point around the projective  space to turn the manifold into $\mathbb RP^n$ connect sum with the inverse exotic sphere. 